# PHP session_write_close() causes empty response

Tags: php, session

When using session_write_close() in a shutdown function at the end of my script - PHP just dies. There is no error logged, response headers (firebug), or data (even whitespace!) returned. I have full PHP error reporting on with STRICT enabled and PHP 5.2.1.

My guess is that since session_write_close() is being called after shutdown - some fatal error is being encountered that crashes PHP before it has a chance to send the output or log anything.

This only happens on the logout page where I first:

```
...
    //If there is no session to delete (not started)
    if ( ! session_id())
    {
        return;
    }

    // Get the session name
    $name = session_name();

    // Delete the session cookie (if exists)
    if ( ! empty($_COOKIE[$name]))
    {
        //Get the current cookie config
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();

        // Delete the cookie from globals
        unset($_COOKIE[$name], $_SESSION);

        //Delete the cookie on the user_agent
        setcookie($name, '', time()-43200, $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['secure']);
    }

    // Destroy the session
    session_destroy();
...
```

then 2) do some more stuff 3) issue a redirect and 4) finally, after the whole page is done the `register_shutdown_function();` I placed earlier runs and calls session_write_close() which saves the session to the database. The end.

Since this blank response only occurs on logout I'm guessing that I'm not restarting the session properly which is causing session_write_close() to die fatally at the end of the script.

Comment: why do you need session_write_close() there?

Comment: To make sure the session is saved in some versions of PHP I think.

Comment: session is writing and closing automatically in the end of script

Comment: PHP 5.0.5 has a bug that requires this - and it shouldn't hurt other versions.

Comment: 5.0.5 is 4 years ago release. and before 5.1.4 php 5.1.x was weird. now you're trying to solve the not exists problem. right?

Comment: PHP 5.0.5 has a bug that requires the session object to save the data before PHP starts removing objects if I remember right. So the problem was that in that older version the database object would be removed before the session class had a chance to save the data. Perhaps I should just remove it since no one should be using PHP 5.0.5 now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird. The problem seems to be the fact that I am destroying the session before I remove the cookie.

This works:

```
    // Delete the session cookie (if exists)
    if ( ! empty($_COOKIE[$name]))
    {
        //Get the current cookie config
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();

        // Delete the cookie from globals
        unset($_COOKIE[$name], $_SESSION);

        //Delete the cookie on the user_agent
        setcookie($name, '', time()-43200, $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['secure']);
    }

    // Destroy the session -----------------------------------------
    session_destroy();
```

while this kills the page:

```
    // Destroy the session -----------------------------------------
    session_destroy();

    // Delete the session cookie (if exists)
    if ( ! empty($_COOKIE[$name]))
    {
        //Get the current cookie config
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();

        // Delete the cookie from globals
        unset($_COOKIE[$name], $_SESSION);

        //Delete the cookie on the user_agent
        setcookie($name, '', time()-43200, $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['secure']);
    }
```

Does anyone know why?